# CNY70 from 5V to 3.3V

Tags: resistors, sensor, voltage-divider

I have CNY70 connected this way:[image: CNY70 schematics]

And I need to determine the value of R2 for OUT to be from 0V to 3.3V.
I don't know how to calculate it, please help.

EDIT:  Input is the 5V and output goes to microcontroller similar to Arduino, but its inputs can't take Voltage higher than 3.3V. So I need to get the output to 0V - 3.3V. I am sorry for being misleading.

EDIT 2: It goes into one of the microcontroller's analog inputs. Not the power supply.

Thank You!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  That doesn't look like a reliable way to get 3.3V as an output.

Comment: short pins 3 and 4 ... why do you believe that any resistor would cause the output to be 3.3 V?

Comment: @JRE How should I get 3.3V as an output?

Comment: Again, what are you trying to do? Do you need 3.3V to power some other device?  Do you need a 3.3V digital signal from a 5V digital signal? Do you need to convert an analog signal that varies between 0 and 5V to an analog signal that varies between 0 and 3.3V?  What is your input, and where does the output go?

Comment: @JRE Input is the 5V and output goes to microcontroller similar to Arduino, but its inputs can't take Voltage higher than 3.3V.

Comment: Then this is a whole lot easier, and it doesn't take an optoisolator to do it.  Add those details to your question.

Comment: Why are you using an opto-isolator then?

Comment: @Andyaka I use it for detecting black and white.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to use an opto-isolator?

Comment: @Andyaka What are better ways to detect black and white on some board?

Comment: Why do you believe you need to use an opto-isolator? I can play this game all day.

Comment: @Andyaka Because I found CNY70 as a solution to my problem.

Comment: Connect the opto collector to the MCU +3.3 volts rather than to +5V.

Comment: What you found as a solution to one problem has become the source of another problem.

Comment: @PeterBennett I am supplying it all with 5V. I can't do that.

Comment: @Wojtic:  Your 3.3V microprocessor has a 3.3V power supply **somewhere.** Use it with the phototransistor from the CNY70.

Comment: @JRE Then I wouldn't need to use R2 at all? I will probably do it this way. I was just wondering if there wasn't an easier way to do it with 5V.

Comment: No!! Do **not** do that.

Comment: @JRE What do you mean?

Comment: I mean Your way, not the one above.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111415/discussion-on-question-by-wojtic-cny70-from-5v-to-3-3v).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it by modifying the value of R2.

You can add a series 510\$\Omega\$ resistor between the +5 and the reflective sensor collector.

Comment: So the value of R2 will stay 1k?

Comment: Yes, it must stay 1K. If you find the sensor is not sensitive enough, increase both resistors proportionally. Eg. 1.5K and 3K.

Comment: Thank you so much. This should solve my problem.

Comment: @Wojtic You are welcome, and welcome to the site. By the way, it's good practice to link the datasheet for your parts such as the [CNY70](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83751/cny70.pdf) which would have made it more clear what you are trying to do.